# Keep bottom line of richtextbox scrolled into view during resize

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, resize

I've got a C# Forms.RichTextBox that autoscrolls to bottom as new lines get added. However; resizing the box leaves the bottom lines in the dust during and after the resizing.

I've tried hooking OnLayout to scroll to bottom if the last frame reported it was at the bottom, but this only works when sizing larger and cuts off the last line beneath the scrollbar, and still leaves the bottom in the dust while sizing smaller. I've got WM_VSCROLL and other user32 stuff hooked up, but I'm not sure how to deal with resizing..

It seems like I should get a ResizeStart to mark whether it was scrolled to bottom, and then a Resize event that should try to keep it there, but there is no ResizeStart. From what I can tell Resize just gets called at every frame with nothing helpful in its eventargs. Help!

I'm open to hosting a WPF control if this would be easier.